# Mac Mini is slow when keyboard and mouse are detached

Tags: keyboard, usb, mouse, mac-mini, kvm

I use a very basic and cheap unit to switch one USB keyboard and one USB mouse between a PC and a Mac Mini. The unit is an [Aten CS22U](https://www.aten.com/gb/en/products/kvm/cable-kvm-switches/cs22u/).

It all works fine, albeit with a few seconds delay when switching to the Mac, for whatever computer the input devices are connected to.

However when the devices are not connected to the Mac it appears to affect the performance of the Mac. Background tasks and any processes slow right down.

The PC (Linux based) works fine with nothing connected.

I have observed this behaviour on all OS versions from 2011 onwards (I can't test Catalina as this Mac Mini isn't supported).

Is there a setting in the Mac to disable this behaviour?

Comment: Have you contacted Aten about this problem?

Comment: No, because it's only evident on macOS I thought that was the source of the "problem".

Comment: If you disconnect the cables from one of the Macs after it starts exhibiting the slowness, and the Mac resumes normal operating speeds, then something about the Aten device is causing problems. Run Activity Monitor on one Mac, click on the CPU header, then switch out of it with the Aten KM. See if there's any process which starts sucking up CPU cycles. In a similar situation 15 years ago, I tested several KVM devices (the V for video as well as keyboard and mouse) I had to get a fairly expensive box to handle screen resolutions correctly and keyboard/mouse connections reliably.

Comment: "If you disconnect the cables from one of the Macs after it starts exhibiting the slowness" - can I improve my question, I'm not sure where I wrote that? The slowness only occurs _while_ the cables are disconnected. I'll have a go at using Activity Monitor though, thanks.

Comment: Maybe I'm not reading your question correctly. The Aten device is a KVM switch connected to a PC and a Mac. Are you using the V part of the KVM, (the video) or just the keyboard & mouse?  I read that when you use the Aten to switch from Mac to PC, the Mac exhibits the slowness. Are you using the V in the KVM?

Comment: No, not the video, just the keyboard and mouse. As you say, when the Aten is switched to the PC the Mac slows down.